# Unknown cfg80211 and wiphy symbols in wl module

Tags: networking, drivers

Since an upgrade to kernel 4.11.0-14 the wl module no longer loads. It fails, listing several wiphy and cfg80211 symbols as missing. In kernel version 4.4 and earlier I can use modprobe to load the cfg80211 module and when I grep for cfg80211 in /lib/modules I find many lines exporting symbols as well as a .ko file. After 4.4 I can only find the .ko file, nothing else.

This install was also originally Xenial but I have since moved all the repositories to Zesty.

I've asked essentially this same question 6 months ago and never received a satisfactory answer but now I'm actually trying to move to Zesty so I decided to ask a new question.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: since kernel 4.4 on ubuntu, you have to have signed modules when secure boot is enabled.

Comment: depends on you comfort level with command line

Comment: I'd say high comfort.

Comment: Sorry, I also noticed a typo in  my question. On 4.4 I don't have any problems.

Comment: `efitools` can be used to create keys to use for signing and add yourkey to the MOK. `sbsigntools` is used to sign the modules